# MPMoviePlayerViewController and automatic status-bar show-hide

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, show-hide, statusbar

There are several posts about MPMoviePlayerViewController and status bar show-hide behavior. None of them seems to give an answer to my issue. Most other similar posts present the problem: how to prevent MPMoviePlayerViewController from automatically hiding status bar. My issue is the opposite. I have implemented a MPMoviePlayerViewController with all its GUI and logic. Now I need to skip from just one video to a sequence of them (urls). For each video I need to determine if controls are to be shown or not. I have noticed that, once I hide them

```
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

even if I show them back, that nice effect of status bar self-hiding according to controls won't work anymore. I can set status bar hidden or not, but I don't seem to be able to get status bar 'automatic hide' to get working again. And of course I would like to avoid changing view-controllers navigation just for this. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any progress?